# Error converting and exporting tbl_df result to xlsx in R

Tags: r

I did the correlation of some variables, however when exporting the results I got an error, because instead of exporting the correlation results the function returns the original data.frame.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(corrplot)
    library(writexl)
    
    veg<-c(1,2,3,2.3,4.1)
    wet<-c(2,2.3,1.9,2.5,2.2)
    dry<-c(5,5.1,6.9,4.3,5.3)
    water<-c(0.69,0.75,0.81,0.82,0.82)
    coli<-c(10,11,12,13,9.7)
    OD<-c(1,3,2.5,2.7,1.8)
    DBO<-c(7,8,9,6.5,8)
    DQO<-c(3.5,4,4.1,3,2)
     
    data_land<-data.frame(veg, wet, dry, water, OD, DBO, DQO)
    
    library(corrr)

    data_land%>%
correlate(method = "spearman")%>%
focus(veg:water)
    
    write_xlsx(data_land, "D:/01-Mestrado/0Dissertacacao/1Rstudio/felipe2/112.xlsx")
```

but when I open the result I see it's the same `data_land` values instead of the correlations

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign your correlations back to `data_land` to have it in this object. Then saving it is `xlsx` should work. Try adding `-> data_land` after the call of `focus`:

```
data_land %>%
  correlate(method = "spearman")%>%
  focus(veg:water) -> data_land

write_xlsx(data_land, "D:/01-Mestrado/0Dissertacacao/1Rstudio/felipe2/112.xlsx")
```

Comment: Wesley the assignment operator `->` (if you start with `data_land = data_land %>% ...` you can use the equal sign, although it is not encouraged) stores the changed object you create with your function calls (i.e. `correlate()` and `focus()`). As you assign it to the same variable name you strictly speaking overwrite it. Thus, if you never do this assignment, the original `data_land` object is unchanged. This is what you originally have written out.